# How to work inline with custom IEqualityComparer<T> parameters

Tags: linq, function, lambda, parameters, distinct

Several time I needed to call linq distincts from different IEnumerables.
These distincts often need criteria that I use just once through the software.
I found really annoying the constraint to create a class that implements the IEqualityComparer with the codebase to perform the distinct, so I thought to cover the gap creating a generic class that allows to point to a lambda expression passed as a parameter of the distinct.

In order to pass a custom IEqualityComparer parameters I developed the following class:

```cs
public class InlineComparer<T>
{
    private class LambdaBasedComparer : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public LambdaBasedComparer(Func<T, int> getHashCode)
        {
            fGetHashCode = getHashCode;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return x?.GetHashCode() == y?.GetHashCode();
        }

        private Func<T, int> fGetHashCode { get; set; }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return fGetHashCode(obj);
        }
    }


    public static IEqualityComparer<T> GetComparer(Func<T, int> getHashCode)
    {
        return new LambdaBasedComparer(getHashCode);
    }
}
```

What do you think about it? I hope it may be helpful!

Of course, a complete implementation of this helper makes use of this class into an extension method similar to "IEnumerable.Distinct(Func getHashCode)", but I wanted to highlight the possibility to work with lambdas to pass the distinct code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :) I'm not sure this question has its place in Stack Overflow. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow. I'm pretty sure it will be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ however!

Comment: Got it. As soon as the 40 minutes pass by I will post there and delete this question then! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your equality comparer will declare two objects to be equal if they return the same value for GetHashCode(). Of course, when defining your own Equality comparer you are free to define the concept of equality any way you want, as long as your equality is reflexive, symmetric and transitive (x==x; if x==y then y==x; if x==y and y==x, then x==z).

Your equality comparer fits these rules, so you can use it.

**However!** Will it be a useful comparer?

You want to use a special equality comparer instead of the default equality comparer because you want some special definition of (un)equality of two objects.

Normally, during your design process you should first define equality of your objects. If you've done that and you want to use your LambdaBasedComparer you'll have to create a Hash Function that will return different values for different objects.

Normally hash functions have one requirement: two equal objects should return the same hash value. There is no requirement upon two different objects.

There are only Int32.MaxValue different Hash values, so if you've designed a class with more than this value possible unequal instances you can't use your comparer. An easy example: try to create a `LambdaBasedComparer<long>` that uses normal equality.

But even if your class can only create half of the Int32.MaxValue instances, it will be very difficult to create a proper hash function that will generate unique hash values for different objects.

Finally your equality will not be very intuitive if you use it to compare derived classes. Consider class Person and derived classes Employee and Customer.

```
IEqualityComparer<Person> personComparer = new LambdBasedComparer<Person>(...);

Person p = new Person(...);
Person e = new Employee(...);
Person c = new Customer(...);
```

Now I can say that a certain Person who isn't an Employee can equal one of your Employees. But would you ever say that Employees will equal Customers?

Summarized: you think that you have a simple solution for your comparers, but it will be very difficult to create a proper hash function for your definition of equality, and it will probably be even more difficult to test this hash function